# How to place Google Maps Marker after each request

Tags: java, google-maps, jsp, servlets, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple web application with JSP page and form on it. Which sends the request with "ID" tag to the servlet. Servlet query this ID to MySQL DB and return an address which is used to create a marker on the map.

I want my application:

1. to show all markers after each request on the map to have
2. opportunity to delete on of them or everyone

But now all I have is updating page and only one marker.

I Will appreciate for any help!

Here is a jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16"/>
    <title>Google Maps Geocoding Demo</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="qwe" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"> ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adress:</td>
            <td>${Street_char} ${Street_name},${Street_adr}, ${Flat_number} floor ${Floor}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>${test}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<br>
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var address = "${address}";
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 18
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address},
            function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Uluru-Test'
                    });
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    new google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker) {
//                    new google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                        return function () {
                            var content = address;
                            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + 'test' + '</strong><br>' + content + '</div>');
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker));

                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                }
                else {
                    // Google couldn't geocode this request. Handle appropriately.
                }
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", value = "/qwe")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    Variables variables = new Variables();
    Variables adr = new Variables(variables.getStreet_char(), variables.getStreet_name(), variables.getStreet_adr());

    String Select_addr = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id=?;";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id_jsp = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(Select_addr);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id_jsp);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                variables.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                variables.setName(resultSet.getString("Name"));
                variables.setSurname(resultSet.getString("Surname"));


    variables.setStreet_char(resultSet.getString("Street_char"));
   variables.setStreet_name(resultSet.getString("Street_name"));
                variables.setStreet_adr(resultSet.getString("Street_adr"));
                variables.setFlat_number(resultSet.getInt("Flat_number"));
                variables.setFloor(resultSet.getInt("Floor"));
            }

            resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println("ID: " + id_jsp + "<br>");

            String adr = "" + variables.getStreet_char() + " " + variables.getStreet_name()
                    + "," + variables.getStreet_adr() + "";
            req.setAttribute("test", adr);
            req.setAttribute("Name", variables.getName());
            req.setAttribute("Surname", variables.getSurname());
            req.setAttribute("Street_char", variables.getStreet_char());
            req.setAttribute("Street_name", variables.getStreet_name());
            req.setAttribute("Street_adr", variables.getStreet_adr());
            req.setAttribute("Flat_number", variables.getFlat_number());
            req.setAttribute("Floor", variables.getFloor());
            req.setAttribute("address", adr);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp").forward(req, resp);

            System.out.println(adr);
//            out.close();
            resultSet.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (preparedStatement != null)
                    preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this. 1. Using Session, In Servlet You need to add all the addresses to a list and put the list in session. In JSP iterate over the address list from session and add multiple markers. 2. Ajax Way, When a button is clicked send an Ajax Request and get the Address as JSON and add the marker using the JSON.

Comment: JChap, how to embody the second way. Could you show some example because I don't know no Ajax no JSON. I want to add marker after each button click and sending an adress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you're setting only one address on each request. Instead you can try fetch all the addresses and make it as a json array and send it to jsp.

In the following sample, I've used `City, Country` for marking. My json array will be like following,

```
[{city: "Manhattan",country:"United States",state:"Manhattan"},
{city:"Newark",country:"United States",state:"Newark"}]
```

My script to initiate and generate markers,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    // Creates the map
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.77627, -73.910965), //For Newyork
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
    }

    // This function takes an array argument containing a list of marker data
    function generateMarkers(locations) {
    //alert(locations);
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map,
          title: locations[i][0]
        });
      }
    }

</script>
```

Here I'm using ajax for loading map. If your json consists of data maybe like above, you can use this function for generate multiple markers.

```
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:250px;;padding-top:0px;margin:25px 50px 25px 55px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function () {
            initialize();
            var d = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "servletURL",
                cache: false,
                async: false
            }).responseText;
            var loc2 = [];
            var locations1 = "";
            if(d.length != 0) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(d);
                $.each(obj, function(key,row) {
                    //alert(row.city + "," + row.country);
                    var address = row.city + "," +row.country;
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        loc2.push("['" + row.city + "'," + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + "," + results[0].geometry.location.lng() +"]");
                        locations1 = "[" + loc2 + "]";
                        generateMarkers(eval(locations1));
                      } 
                      else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                      }
                    });
                }); 
            }
        };
      </script>
</div>
```

See the generated output with multiple markers,

[image: Google map with multiple markers]

And for *deleting the markers*, I would recommend you to update the json and load it again. Hope this helps.

**Update :**

This is how my business logic fetch the data. I'm using `Spring & Hibernate`. I'm using `jackson` jar file. It will convert java object to json. You can use `Gson` also.

```
public List<GoogleMapHelper> getAddressForGoogleMap() {
    String sql = "Select city, state, country FROM dbo.Customerdetails ";
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    List data = query.list();
    List<GoogleMapHelper> address = new ArrayList<GoogleMapHelper>();
    for (Object object : data) {
        GoogleMapHelper googleHelper = new GoogleMapHelper();
        Map row = (Map) object;
        googleHelper.setCity(row.get("city").toString());
        googleHelper.setState(row.get("state").toString());
        googleHelper.setCountry(row.get("country").toString());
        address.add(googleHelper);
    }
    return address;
}
```

And my `GoogleMapHelper` is nothing but POJO class,

```
public class GoogleMapHelper {

    private String city;

    private String state;

    private String country;

    (getters and setters)

}
```

Comment: Thank you Vinoth Krishnan for your answer!.
Can I put values after each click ( increase ) this json array? If yes how to do it?
`[{city: "Manhattan",country:"United States",state:"Manhattan"},
{city:"Newark",country:"United States",state:"Newark"}]`
As for about deleting the markers_ I need to delete not all togather, but chosen by the address (after putting the address to the form, sending it to servlet)

Comment: Where is your address coming from? If it's from db, keep a flag for each address. If one address has chosen for display mark it true. In case of delete mark it false. Otherwise you got to store it in session.

Comment: At first db table is clean, But user from html form puts such information to db: 
    **Name of street:**  _Madison St_
    **Street adress:** _75_
    **City:** _New York_
and servlet return marker on the map.
Than user add next information, and servlet must return one more marker on the map. and so on. If user decide to delete some marker he will requst a query to db and servlet must delete this marker, but others must stay on map

Comment: Sure, your requirement is simple. So all of the address in your table should be available as markers in google map. Write a separate function to fetch the address and city. Convert as `Json Array` return it to ajax. This will populate the markers. If you're deleting an address it will not be available in your table too (I hope). So it will not be available in your map.

Comment: I've added my java part also, hope it might be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you Vinoth Krishnan for your big help. But now I'm more confused, because I don't know no `Spring` no `Hibernate`. Could I use JDBC instead Hibernate and to do it without Spring? Also I need to learn json and ajax because as I told earlier I'm beginner and don't know this technologies. I will continue with my question when I will have more specific understanding of what you told me.

Comment: Of course you can use servlet & JDBC. It's all about the data format required for google map(i.e, `json`). You can bring it how you know. If this post you find it as useful do an upvote and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it as answer. Might be useful for someone.

Comment: At first I will study a little bit, and will try to do like you suggest. And when I'll complete my task, I will accept it as answer.Thank you.